# Appium and android studio

Tags: android, appium

I have installed Appium on ubuntu and make my first test using java command in an android studio while running my test I get an error

> A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new
>   session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide
>   any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 603.92
>   seconds

```
public class MyTest {

    AndroidDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void testCaseSetup()throws  Exception {
        //service.start();
        //reader.readFile();
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus_5");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "v1.4.7");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.example.nitish.myappium");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, ".MainActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }


        @Test

        public void testcase1()throws  Exception
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.nitish.myappium:id/front")).click();

        }

    @After
    public void testCaseTearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Comment: Just kill the old appium server, restart and try again. Or just wait the old session finish. It will take some time to quit the session after the last test run.

Comment: Nothing happens i have killed my appium server and restarted.

Comment: Though not much shall ideally change, but could you try adding this `cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");` and also share the appium server logs with whatever the reult be.

Comment: plz share your email id Appium server logs have  too long charactees

Comment: please share your email id Appium server logs have too long characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.0.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Device Name");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.nitish.myappium");

    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

}
```

Comment: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: it worked as i solve the problem the actuaaly error was "missing android sdk path".

Answer (score 0):

This error means the server seeion is already there for port 4273 try changing server port number and give the same port number in your code

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:**4723**/wd/hub"), cap);
```